# JQUERY & Select box not updating database

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

I have the following 3 checkboxes which are populated from a php database. I need assistance with JQUERY that once any select box is changed the value is posted to a php file and able to return a response through JQUERY.

Each select box should be standalone to only send that checkbox value & name to the PHP file.

I have the below JQUERY to start with to send the first checkbox but am getting no response back.

What amendments need to be made to the JQUERY to receive the input of the other checkboxes and then send the data correctly?

The php file will simply have echo "WHAT EVER THE RESPONSE IS" using if statements.

Any help grately appreciated with thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.person-1').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/positionMarshalProcess.php',
        data: {
          selectFieldValue: $('select.person-1').val(),
          changeCol1: $('input[name$="changeCol1"]').val()
        },
        dataType: "html",
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var a = data.split('|***|');
        if (a[1] == "update") {
          $('#msg').html(a[0]);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='person-1' class='marshal-select'>
<option value='1'>John Smith</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='changeCol1' value='person-1'>

<select name='qty' class='marshal-select'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='changeCol2' value='qty'>

<select name='person-2' class='marshal-select'>
<option value='1'>John Smith</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' name='changeCol3' value='person-2'>
```

Comment: There is no `select.person-1` or `input[name$="changeCol1"]` elements in the HTML sample. You also have a syntax error in the `$.ajax` call as you've placed `success` outside of the settings object. Check the console in devtools to debug that error.

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for this. Can you clarify what you mean by select.person-1 - the select name is person-1 ? However I am keen to learn how to post any 3 of the select boxes to JQUERY not just person-1.

Comment: `.person-1` is a class selector, not a name selector. I added an answer for you below.

Comment: Hi Rory - thank you for this. I am having difficulty with where to place the code and what to add to physically push to the php file, could you kindly add these lines in for me?

Comment: Hi Rory, thank you for all your help. Could I kindly you ask you assist me with the final touch which is posting the PHP row ID. I think this may have to be in a hidden field. In essence I am looping through a table called 'positions' and placing the select boxes which are all sending correctly but the output of the select boxes needed to be updated in [positionNo] from the database. I have tried a hidden field but this only posts ID for row 1 and does not continue down.

Answer (score 0):

The selectors you've used are incorrect for the HTML displayed. `.person-1` is a *class* selector, yet the `select` elements have that value in their `name`.

In addition your `success` property is outside the options object of the `$.ajax` call - it needs to be inside.

You can fix this issue and DRY up the code to make it more extensible by removing the hidden fields, hooking the `change` event handler to the common `marshal-select` class on all the `select` elements, and by using the `name` attribute of the `select` elements to fill the `changeCol` property of the data you send in the AJAX request. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.marshal-select').change(function() {
    let $select = $(this);

    // in your AJAX request...
    let data = {
      selectFieldValue: $select.val(),
      changeCol: $select.prop('name')
    };

    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="person-1" class="marshal-select">
  <option value="1">John Smith</option>
  <option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
</select>

<select name="qty" class="marshal-select">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select name="person-2" class="marshal-select">
  <option value="1">John Smith</option>
  <option value="2">Jane Doe</option>
</select>
```

As an aside, the logic in the `success` handler implies that you're returning plain text and then hacking the string around using `split()`. Do not do this. Return a serialised data structure, such as JSON instead. This is more extensible and makes the code far more robust.

---

*Update:*

> With your code you have added could you just add an edit where how you would receive a response ideally I want a positive response to show the msg div and where you would call the php file?

Sure, here you go:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.marshal-select').change(function() {
    let $select = $(this);
    
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'lib/positionMarshalProcess.php',
      data: {
        selectFieldValue: $select.val(),
        changeCol: $select.prop('name')
      },
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        // assuming a JSON response:
        if (data[1] === 'update') {
          $('#msg').html(data[0]).show();
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Note that I've not included the PHP which would generate the JSON response as I'm not a PHP dev. I'm sure there are lots of topics covering that if you search.

Comment: Rory, thank you so much this works a treat. One error my side which I have come across is these drop down boxes are being run as a while loop so I also need to send the row ID. I can use a hidden field for positionNo and have manged to send this through but it is always sending only the value of the first row. Are you able to assist?